# Как сделать функцию превращающую координаты в градусы?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть координаты x и y
И мне нужно создать такую функцию

```
function fun(degrees, distance) { 
var x1 = distance * Math.cos(degrees); 
var y1 = distance * Math.sin(degrees);   
var arr = [x1, y1];
return arr;
}
alert (fun(90, 5)) ;
```

В которой если X и Y равно 0

то значения

> degrees = 0 distance=5 будут равны X=0 Y=5
>
> degrees = 90 distance=5 будут равны X=5 Y=0
>
> degrees = 180 distance=5 будут равны X=0 Y=-5
>
> degrees = 270 distance=5 будут равны X=-5 Y=0
>
> degrees = 360 distance=5 будут равны X=0 Y=5

Но я не знаю как ее получить особенно когда

> degrees = 100 distance=5 будут равны X=?? Y=??

Comment: Ну стандартный же перевод декартовых координат в полярные...

Comment: декартовые координаты в полярные, формула: `p=sqrt(x^2+y^2); tg(f)=y/x; cos(f)=x/sqrt(x^2+y^2); sin(f)=y/sqrt(x^2+y^2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x2,у2 - конец вектора, х1,у1 - начало вектора.
х1,у1 можно принять нулю если угол нужно определить от начала координат.

```
dx = x2-x1
dy = y2-y1

angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
distance = Math.sqrt(dy*dy + dx*dx)
```

перевод обратно

```
x2 = x1 + Math.cos(angle)*distance
y2 = y1 + Math.sin(angle)*distance
```

angle в радианах тут везде. Перевод в градусы

```
degrees  = angle*180/Math.PI

angle = degrees*Math.PI/180
```

Comment: А что у вас находится в x1 x2 и y1 y2? мне нужно найти  x1 и y2.

Comment: x2,у2 - конец вектора, х1,у1 - начало вектора

Comment: Вы имели в веду сделать так? `var cos = Math.cos(degrees)/(Math.PI/180) ;
var sin = Math.sin(degrees)/(Math.PI/180) ;   

var x1 = distance * cos;
var y1 = distance * sin; 
  
var arr = [x1, y1]

return arr;`

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду то что написал)  ваши формулы похожи на правильные.

Comment: Тогда скажите где я допустил ошибку? https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/zYGWdZG?editors=0010

Comment: тут нет ошибки, считает верно!  3.0...e-16 это примерно ноль. погрешность округления числа Пи так влияет. округлите значения до нужной точности